# how to integrate UINavigationController with React-Native component

Tags: ios, react-native

In my recent work, I use React-Native component as the view part of an `iOS` app. When I write "full native app", let's say I have button on the view, I click it and the `UINavigationController` would push in a new `ViewController`:

```
 UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 60, 200, 60)];    
 btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];    
 [btn setTitle:@"btn" forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
 [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(clickme:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
 ...

 - (void) clickme: (UIButton*) sender{
   [self.navController pushViewController:ANOTHER_VIEW_CONTROLLER animated:YES];
 }
```

so my question is: how can I do this in a React-Native Component?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem and solution is in this issue：https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3324

lol~

Answer (score 0):

```
this.props.navigator.push({...});
```

See [NavigatorIOS](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigatorios.html#content) and [Navigator](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#content) for more details.

Comment: I don't mean how to use NavigatorIOS or Navigator Component, I want to know how integrate native UINavigationController with react-native component